# can't understand a code line about powerbuilder 11.5 's SQLCA

Tags: powerbuilder, sql-calc-found-rows

cause the SQLCA is an built in object, i can't find it in my program , and i also can't find `of_init_inifile()` function too, where can i find it? and how?
in my program(powerbuilder 11.5), i saw a line like this:

```
SQLCA.of_init_inifile(gnv_app.of_getAppINIFile(),"DataBase")
```

my powerbuilder version is 11.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example given looks to be from a PFC (PowerBuilder Foundation Classes) based application.  The function on `SQLCA` would be defined on the `Transaction` object.  The `of_getAppINIFile` function is defined on the global application object.

If you bring up the application from the pbl (the object inherited from 'application'), then click on the 'Additional Properties' button, you will bring up a popup window with a tab control containing various property settings.  Click on the 'Variable Types' tab to see the value contained in the `SQLCA` property.  A common example might be `n_tr`.  You can then examine the `n_tr` class (look in `pfemain.pbl`) to see the code for `of_init_inifile` (it may be in an ancestor of `n_tr` as well).

The global application object is normally inherited from `n_cst_appmanager` -
 look in the `pfeapsrv.pbl` (inherited from `pfc_n_cst_appmanager` - look in the `pfcapsrv.pbl`).

Comment: thank you Matt, i found n_tr inherit from transaction object, but when i try my own code, i new an object inherit from n_cst_appmanager, then i code like this "SQLCA.of_init_inifile()" it occurs an compling error: unkwon fuction of_init_infile(). is there any similar things in pb like java's polymorphism? and i really want to know how to use it?

Comment: i changed type of SQLCA in  the 'Additional Properties' , then i can complie of_init_inifile();thank you again Matt, god bless u.